# count and search combined in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table and each row is a different class.  One of the columns has student names separated by commas.  I want to make another table that shows the number of classes that the student is in.  Basically, what I need is a DAX formula to combine search and countrows.  The first table is what I am starting with.  The second table is what I want but cannot figure out an easy way to do it.

I can only think of creating a separate table for each student and then use union to put them all together.
[table 1 is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLA1Z.jpg)

[Table 2 is what I want in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbvsS.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible like you want to do it, you need to redesign your first table. This datarow

```
Class      Students
Physics      A, B
```

has to look like this:

```
Class      Students
Physics       A
Physics       B
```

You can do this in the under edit querys. Select the column `Students` and click on `Transform > Split Column > By Delimiter`. Chose `Comma` as delimiter and go to the advanced option and check the `Rows` option. If you hit OK you get the table like you need it to evaluate your data.